# Dictionary handling using depth first search in python

Tags: python, dictionary, depth-first-search

i want to traverse `dic` and i am using dfs for this.

For which i have to take care of 2 cases:

1. if  i traversed all of the values of a particular key and made that list of value for that key empty by popping elements.
2. if a particular key does not exist

Now if i use (if len(dic.get(key)))!=0, I am getting this error:

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len().

And if i use `(if dic.get(key) is not None)` I get this error:

> e=dic[stack[-1]][0]
> IndexError: list index out of range

Is there a way through i can handle both the cases?

```py
dic = {"JFK": ["MUC"], "LHR": ["SFO"], "MUC": ["LHR"], "SFO": ["SJC"]}

ans = []
stack = []
stack.append("JFK")

while stack:
    if len(dic.get(stack[-1])) != 0 or dic.get(stack[-1]) != None:

        g = stack[-1]
        e = dic[stack[-1]][0]
        stack.append(e)

        f = dic.get(g)

        f.pop(0)

    else:
        e = stack.pop()
        ans.append(e)
print(ans[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this generator function:

```
dic = {"JFK": ["MUC"], "LHR": ["SFO"], "MUC": ["LHR"], "SFO": ["SJC"]}


def traverse(tree, start):
    stack = [start]
    while stack:
        el = stack.pop(-1)
        yield el
        stack.extend(tree.get(el, []))


for node in traverse(dic, "JFK"):
    print(node)
```

- This will happily end up in an endless loop if there are loops in the graph.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but i am new to python and i don;t really know how yield works